# Run truffle test without recompile every time?

Tags: truffle

Is there a way to run truffle test and not recompile the solidity code each time? 
It takes a lot of time if i just want to play around with the javascript tests...

Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

[Since January 2020](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/2661) Truffle suite has option `--compile-none`

With this option enabled it tests compiled contracts from `build/contracts` directory.

Here is how it looks like in Truffle v5.1.55:

```
PS D:\work\ERC20> truffle test  --compile-none                        
Using network 'test'.


Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.
```

Comment: Thank you, this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/469) with truffle. As of Nov 2018 and the latest version 4.1.14, there is no out-of-the-box solution. There is a [workaround](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/469#issuecomment-401413419), albeit a bit messy:

Create an empty folder called `migrations_null` and then run your tests like this:

```
truffle test --migrations_directory migrations_null
```

Comment: It only solves the problem with migration, but then I don't have an access to my contracts. It says that they were not deployed. It will still compile all contracts.